# Whats is the best way to check URL document link existence?

Tags: c#, asp.net, validationattribute

I need to check the validity of the URL to different files without opening the link document/image. I used the below code in ASP.net 4.7.2 in validation attribute. The current code is as follows : (working fine with jpg)

```
public override bool IsValid(object DocumentURL)
        {
            try
            {
                string urlLink = (string)DocumentURL;
                WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(urlLink);
                request.GetResponse();
                return true;
            }
            catch 
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

This works for images but failed when I sent a link to xls file.
The error message is :

```
"The request entity's media type 'text/plain' is not supported for this resource"
No mediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'W_Document_URL' media type 'text/plain'."
```

This looks like my function is trying to open the document. I need only to check the existence of the URL document but does not need to open it. 
Also if I need to restrict the documents to images(jpeg,png,bmp) and pdf, what is the best way to limit that inside this function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to send a [`HEAD` request](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.4). Quoting w3.org:

> The metainformation contained in the HTTP headers in response to a HEAD request SHOULD be identical to the information sent in response to a GET request.
>
> This method is often used for testing hypertext links for validity, accessibility, and recent modification and for obtaining metainformation about the entity implied by the request without transferring the entity-body itself.

As for the implementation, maybe check out [this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/14b3ee11-0492-4111-b6c5-217b5fcf0a2e/sending-a-http-head-request-in-c?forum=winappswithcsharp), example snippet by AlexandreJBRodrigues:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

HttpRequestMessage request = 
   new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Head, 
      new Uri("http://iamauri.com"));

HttpResponseMessage response = 
   await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
```